# Angular - Data loss using nested template

Tags: angular

For the purpose of having controls in a  nested template driven form, I am using this

```
viewProviders: [ { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm } ]
```

as explained on this [article](https://medium.com/@a.yurich.zuev/angular-nested-template-driven-form-4a3de2042475).

It's working pretty good for simple usages. But now I am facing an issue with this. Let's see an example ([stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n1hjpp?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)). Let's say we have a loop over addresses. There is a button to add a new addresss.

```
<button (click)="addAddress()">Add</button>
<ng-container *ngFor="let address of addresses; index as i">
  <fieldset ngModelGroup="address{{i}}">
    <address [address]="address"></address>
  </fieldset>
</ng-container>
```

If you add a new address (try in stackblitz) you'll see data is removed in the inputs of the first component. But what strange is data in the model is still there.

[image]

When I look at augury and the controls, I see that input aren't at the good place. There should be under the FormGroup.

[image]

So I am sure there is something to do with this line

```
viewProviders: [ { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm } ]
```

like replace NgForm by NgModelGroup or something like that. I've been searching around the angular docs but couldn't find any useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fieldset with `ngModelGroup` directive needs to be in the component.

```
<button (click)="addAddress()">Add</button>
<ng-container *ngFor="let address of addresses; index as i">
    <address [address]="address" [index]="index"></address>
</ng-container>
```

In the address component template

```
<fieldset ngModelGroup="address{{index}}">
 <input ....
</fieldset>
```

Working [stackbitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-natrgk?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)